# How to assign field access to multiple permission sets at a time

Tags: permissions, permission-sets, field-update, access

I have a requirement where i need to provide read and edit access to object fields in 18 different permission sets.

This looks like lot of manual work and will consume lot of time. Is there anyway where we can automate this process so that we can assign field access to multiple permission sets at a time.

Please suggest

Comment: Consider using an AppExchange offering such as [BOFPerMan](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FtWcBUAV).

Comment: If you are comfortable using sfdx or the metadata API, you could do this for yourself using some scripting of some form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to comments , you can also simply prepare a csv file and insert all permissions in "FieldPermission" object.

Snapshot of excel to be inserted

[image]

In the snapshot below is understanding of each column :

Field --> Denotes your ObjectApiName.FieldApiName

ParentId --> It is the id of permission set you want to give access to. In case of profiles (Find its wrapper permission set by querying on permission set object)

PermissionEdit --> If edit permission allowed.

PermissionRead -> If read permission allowed.

SobjectType    -> Again object api name

Once csv is ready simply go to your preferred tool (workbench) and insert the csv records

Note : Manual efforts are required in this method as well.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!!